# How to append text after last css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following html

```
<div class="someClass">  
    Some text  
</div>  
<div class="someClass">  
    Some other text  
</div>
<div class="add>
    <img src="someImage.jpg">
</div>
```

Now I'd like to append another *div* after a click on the add image - but only after the last div with the class "someClass".

If I use the following jQuery it will be appended after each someClass element, so multiple times.

```
$(".add img").live("click", function() {
    $(".containerFooter").after("<div class='someClass'>test</div>");
});
```

Is there a way to only append it after the last div with the someClass attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector:

```
$(".someClass:last").after("<div class='someClass'>test</div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.someClass').last()
```

OR

```
$('.someClass:last')
```

will give you last element of class `someclass`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$(".someClass").last().append("<div class='someClass'>test</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, dint read the question completely in first attempt, updated the ans!

Also your html has a typo , its  make it

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/gaMDM/2/)

```
$(".someClass").last() //-> selects your last div with id = someClass

.after("<div class='someClass'>test</div>");//-> place the html after the selected div
```

Actual code below

```
   $(".add").live("click", function(){
  $(".someClass").last().after("<div class='someClass'>test</div>");
});
​
    ​
```

Comment: That appends it after the `.add` div.  He wants it before that but after the last `.someClass` div

Comment: Fix your selector `$('.someClass')`  - > also he only wants it after last div element with that class so you filter for that also

Comment: wow, thanks for your help. I did correct these in demo, but forgot to copy here!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".add img").live("click", function() {
    $(".someClass:last").after("<div class='someClass'>test</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way, but a jquery class returns an array of applicable objects. So you can find the last such object, create a new jquery object from it, and then operate on that.

```
<html><title>JQuery Play</title>
<h1>JQuery Play</h1>
<script src="jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add()
{
var x=$(".someClass");
$(x[x.length-1]).after("Added text");
}
</script>
<div class="someClass">   
    Some text   
</div>   
<div class="someClass">   
    Some other text   
</div> 
<div class="add"> 
    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
</div> 

</html>
```